Distance weighted mean - how to handle samples at the same location
In R, I am calculating differences in community composition for several samples in a certain area. To get an overall measure of how different the communities are, I want to weigh samples that are closer together more than samples that are farther apart. To do this, I have a matrix containing the dissimilarity between samples:
> dissimilarity_m
          1         2
2 0.7258861          
3 0.9378651 0.9253090

and a matrix showing the spatial distance:
> dist_m
            1           2
2 0.000000000            
3 0.009437432 0.009437432

However, I am now struggling how to best calculate the weighted mean. So far I have used
dist_mean_weighed <- weighted.mean(dissimilarity_m, w = 1/dist_m)

but I wonder if the inverse distance 1/w is a good approximation. Also, this of course does not work if two samples are at the same location and w = 0 (all my samples are recorded with coordinates, which are not at a meter resolution and therefore  several samples have a distance of zero).
Is there a better approximation or even a more useful function in R?

You could try exponential weighting, e.g. exp(-dist_m * C) where C is some constant that affects how steep the dropoff is as your "samples" grow farther apart
